# Ambiguïté sur « ses extrêmes faiblesses. »

Tags: sens, possessif, antécédent

À Notre-Dame dimanche soir, l'Archevêque Vingt-Trois dit la phrase ci-dessous dans son homélie :

> Ce n’est pas en décapitant que l’on montre la grandeur de Dieu, c’est en travaillant au respect de l’être humain jusque dans ses extrêmes faiblesses.

Je ne comprends pas le sens des trois mots finaux. Qui semblerait avoir les faiblesses dans cette phrase : l'homme qui veut montrer la grandeur de Dieu, ou l'être humain qui est respecté ?

Pour moi, il est logique que c'est le premier, mais il n'est pas complètement clair, et l'autre option change le sens considérablement.

Comment: Ma compréhension de la phrase, ce sont les extrêmes faiblesses de l'être humain (celui que l'on respecte). L'Homme est imparfait, c'est acté, mais cela ne doit pas mener à un mépris ou un manque de respect pour autant. Le respect est nécessaire.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I'd translate the Archbishop's words to English as follows: ... "We exalt God, not by decapitating [in His name] a fellow human being, but rather by working to respect him/her, right down to the biggest of her/his many weaknesses." ... which puts me in agreement with @Chop and his comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grammaticalement, un adjectif possessif, comme un pronom, renvoie à une entité précédemment mentionnée. La forme de l'adjectif possessif ou du pronom peut imposer des contraintes sur l'entité telles que le nombre, le genre et la personne. L'adjectif possessif *ses* exige un possédant qui est à la troisième personne du singulier (et de genre indifférent), il renvoie donc à une entité singulière, autre que la personne qui parle ou la personne à laquelle le discours s'adresse.

La règle de base est que l'adjectif possessif ou le pronom renvoie à la dernière entité mentionnée qui convient grammaticalement. Toutefois, souvent, une entité mentionnée dans un complément d'une entité convenable ne compte pas. Exemple :

> J'ai croisé un homme qui promenait son chien. Il m'a dit bonjour.
>   J'ai croisé un homme qui promenait son chien. Il n'arrêtait pas d'aboyer.

Dans cet exemple, il n'y a pas d'ambiguïté sémantique. Dans le premier exemple, *il* renvoie à l'homme ; dans le deuxième, *il* renvoie au chien. Je trouve le deuxième exemple moins naturel même s'il est compréhensible : j'aurais tendance à dire « Le chien n'arrêtait pas d'aboyer ». C'est l'homme qui est l'antécédent préféré, parce que le chien est mentionné dans un complément.

> Mon voisin promenait son chien. Il m'a dit bonjour.
>   Mon voisin promenait son chien. Il n'arrêtait pas d'aboyer.

Ici encore, je trouve le deuxième exemple moins naturel. Bien que le sujet apparaisse plus tôt, il est préféré au complément du verbe.

Venons-en à la phrase citée dans la question. Il n'y a pas moins de quatre entités convenables : « Dieu », « on », « [le] respect de l'être humain » et « l'être humain ». Si l'on suit la règle de la dernière mention, l'antécédent serait « l'être humain ». Mais si l'on élimine les compléments, « le respect … » devrait être préféré à « l'être humain ». Le lien avec « on » est également affaibli par le fait qu'il est situé dans un complément (une subordonnée relative). Le lien avec « Dieu », complément d'un complément d'un complément, est le plus faible des quatre.

L'antécédent le plus naturel m'apparaît donc comme étant « le respect … » : il est au même niveau de complément que « on » mais considérablement plus proche. Toutefois, sémantiquement parlant, « le respect … » ne convient pas. Il faut donc départager « on » et « l'être humain ». Le second est plus imbriqué (à un niveau de complément supplémentaire), mais considérablement plus proche : lorsque l'on entend la phrase, quand « ses extrêmes faiblesses » arrive, on a déjà oublié le « on ». Du coup, à l'oral, le lien avec « l'être humain » est nettement plus naturel. À l'écrit, la phrase est plus ambigüe, il faut trancher sémantiquement.

En quoi les extrêmes faiblesses sont-elles importantes ? Essayons de tourner la phrase à la première personne.

> Ce n’est pas en décapitant que je peux montrer la grandeur de Dieu, c’est en travaillant au respect de l’être humain jusque dans [mes/ses] extrêmes faiblesses.

S'agit-il alors de *mes* extrêmes faiblesses ? Ceci signifierait que l'étendue du travail de respect est importante, alors que l'opposition dans la phrase porte de l'action : décapiter ou travailler au respect de quelque chose. Bien que cela soit logiquement possible, cette interprétation rend la phrase mal équilibrée.

Si l'on conserve « ses extrêmes faiblesses », la phrase n'est pas ambigüe, puisqu'il ne reste qu'un antécédent préféré, qui est « l'être humain ». Et le complément « jusque dans ses extrêmes faiblesses » prend ici tout son sens : il faut non seulement respecter l'être humain, mais il faut le respecter même s'il montre d'extrêmes faiblesses, sous-entendu des faiblesses qui pourraient nous conduire à ne pas le trouver respectable.

J'en conclus qu'aussi bien à l'oral qu'à l'écrit, l'interprétation selon laquelle ce « ses » renvoie à « l'être humain » est la plus naturelle.

Comment: [Discussion afférente sur le salon de clavardage](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25460200#25460200)

Comment: Impeccable ! Merci beaucoup ! Je me sens que je suis maintenant juste un peu mieux à la langue française.